# How to show how many database hits my view makes

Tags: django

I have a queryset that I use in my view and I want to know how many times it's hitting the database.
Is there a way to show every hit or count them? Or do I need to know the inner workings of every generic Class Based View to estimate the sum?

Comment: https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar

Comment: No, this doesn't help.